# How to send HTML via JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I am trying to send the html of a template via an AJAX request, and I need to use JSONP to not get a cross origin error, but right now I need to set data type as jsonp. As a result, the ajax gets the template and I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" and when I console.log(data) I get "jQuery1640440755290677771_1319300298806 was not called". How can I fix the ajax call so I can get my html for the underscore.js template to use?

Thanks.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    cache: "false",
    crossDomain:"true",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "f00");
    },
    success: function(html) {
        console.log(html);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste your complete json to [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) see what breaks it. Try using single quotes on the html for example.

Comment: It's not JSON, it's just an HTML page. Is this impossible to do with an AJAX call?

Comment: If you set dataType as jsonp then it expects jsonp and throws error on html. And as you said setting dataType as html will give cross origin error or security violation error on some browsers. You'll have to write your own backend service to go around this (to my knowledge).

Answer (score 0):

Use the list option of the `dataType` property. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for details, but TL;DR is use `datatype: "jsonp html"`. Otherwise it's going to be expecting JSON back, not HTML.

You'll likely need to wrap the HTML content as JSON, but you may have been doing that already.

Answer (score 0):

JSONP is of the form:

```
funcName({"key": "value"})
```

that is, a function call passing an object. All you have to do is to assign your HTML template to a property of this object. The result should be:

```
funcName({"template": "<p>Template</p>"})
```

You have to set up your server accordingly.

---

Another option would be to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` response header at your server (and then of course do not specify `json` as data type in the Ajax call).

See [*Cross-Origin Resource Sharing*](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) for more information.